# JtaTransaction localStatus rolled back after creation

Tags: java, hibernate, jta

I'm creating a hibernate `Session` and try to start a new [Jta]Transaction. Though, the transaction cannot be started because the JtaTransaction that is used in the background seems to be rolled back.

Here is what I'm doing.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
CustomSessionWrapper dpSession = new CustomSessionWrapper(session, this);

if (!session.isClosed() && !session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
    session.beginTransaction();
}
```

Nevertheless the transaction is still not active after the `beginTransaction` is called. When I debug the `beginTransaction` method I come to the `doBegin` method of the `JtaTransaction` (I do not override this method, I'm just posting the original code of this method).

```
@Override
protected void doBegin() {
    LOG.debug( "begin" );

    userTransaction = locateUserTransaction();

    try {
        if ( userTransaction.getStatus() == Status.STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION ) {
            userTransaction.begin();
            isInitiator = true;
            LOG.debug( "Began a new JTA transaction" );
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        throw new TransactionException( "JTA transaction begin failed", e );
    }
}
```

The `userTransaction.getStatus()` returns `Status.STATUS_ROLLEDBACK` and no transaction is started. Does anyone know how I can fix that?

**UPDATE 1** (you can skip that since that was a mistake, see UPDATE 2)

I found out that there are two threads, one using the main session and another using smaller sessions for logging. The main session (and transaction) is open for a longer period of time, so basically until the operation is finished. It seems that `locateUserTransaction` always returns the same `userTransaction`. This means that the main session opens this userTransaction and one of the side transactions commit/rollback that transaction. Does anyone know what to do so that different transactions are retrieved?

**UPDATE 2**

I found out that I don't have two threads, it is only one threads that opens two sessions in parallel. Each session should then open their own transaction, though both get the same UserTransaction. How can I tell hibernate that each session should get its own [User]Transaction?

Comment: Have you closed session every where in your application?

Comment: Yes, the session is always closed when the `commit` or `rollback` method of the `CustomSessionWrapper` class is called.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate abstracts both local as JTA transactions behind its own abstraction layer, so I don't see why you'd have to write such low level transaction handling code.

In Java EE you have the app server to manage transactions, in stand alone apps Bitronix + Spring do a job too.

Although you can manage to write your own transaction management logic, I always advice people to reuse what they have already available. Xa/JTA and Hibernate require extensive knowledge to work seamlessly.

**Update 1**

Two different threads shouldn't use the same user transaction, you should use different transactions for each thread.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Sadly there are two reasons why I can't use this approach (although I would if I could...). First the code has to work for webservices and fatclients. The webservices use jta whereas the fatclients use jdbc. Second, this code is in a huge codebase so rewriting everything is not possible. We recently upgraded from hibernate 3.2 to 4.3 and since then this problem occurs...

Comment: I also do not override the doBegin method, I just posted the original code in order to tell you what I found out.

Comment: I understand. Well, if the transaction was marked as rollbacked you can't use it any more, the only solution is to start a new one. Because transactions are bound to threads you must let it rollback, exit the transaction boundary and retry from the the nearest outer point of where the transaction boundary starts (usually the @Transactional service). I usually do this with AOP, where I simply retry if the transaction has failed but it's recoverable (e.g. optimistic locking, deadlocks). It's mandatory to investigate what makes your transaction being roll backed.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently on it what rolls back the transaction.

Comment: I think I found out what rolls back the transaction and updated the question. Maybe you know something :)

Comment: I think each thread should sue its own transaction and definitely its own Session.

Comment: each thread does call openSession. Though in the beginTransaction for both sessions the same userTransaction is used...

Comment: Actually I just found out that the same thread opens two sessions (which both try to open a transaction). Maybe this is the problem?