# Multiple simultaneous hibernate sessions per thread

Tags: java, hibernate, session, transactions

I'm working on a REST webservice that uses hibernate as an OR Mapper. I recently upgraded hibernate from 3.2 to 4.3 and got an error I [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411519/jtatransaction-localstatus-rolled-back-after-creation). Basically my transaction got rolled back somewhere and then I got an error when I wanted to use that session again (which is correct hibernate behavior).

I think I figured out why I got that error. It is because when I receive the request a long session is started. This session also opens a transaction that will be open for a longer period of time. Besides this long running session/transaction also some small session/transaction should be opened on the same thread. As far as I found out, all sessions get the same `UserTransaction` to work with and since the small transactions commit and rollback this transaction I run in the error described in my other post.

Since I'm working with a huge code base it is that easy to change the code so that all that side session run in a different thread (in case that would help) or to refactor the whole service so that only one transaction can be open at any time.

**Actual Question starts here**

Is there any possibility to start multiple simultaneous sessions/transactions in one Thread? If so, what would I have to do, to tell hibernate to do that? If this is not possible what way of accomplishing a similar behavior would you suggest?

**Code snippet I use to create the sessions**

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
CustomSessionWrapper dpSession = new CustomSessionWrapper(session, this);

if (!session.isClosed() && !session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
    session.beginTransaction();
}
```

The code worked before I upgraded hibernate so the problem should not be in the `CustomSessionWrapper` or any other custom class.

Thanks a lot in advance!